# Are preservatives applied to commercially distrubted fruit?

Tags: fruit, organic-food

I recently had a discussion over some fruit that rotted a lot faster that we expected. I was told that this was a good sign because it meant that the fruit was grown more naturally (probably without preservatives).

Is it a common practice for industrial agriculture to apply preservatives to fruit?

[this website](http://www.organicfoods101.com/organic-food-blog/what-chemicals-are-used-with-organic-foods/)  and [this other](http://www.progressiveic.com/n28may05.htm) claim that lack of wax causes this effect

they also claim this effect [here](http://student.sheboyganfalls.k12.wi.us/14malamb/food-culture/)

Comment: You are skeptical if chemical preservatives applied to fruit work?  Or just if they are actually used in commercially distributed fruit?

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: Ugh, looks complex: "Conventionally grown kiwifruits were ﬁrmer than
organic ones and remained signiﬁcantly ﬁrmer until
35 days of storage. This is in contrast to what
was observed by Hasey et al.,who found organic
kiwifruits as ﬁrm or ﬁrmer than conventional
kiwifruits, and by Benge et al., who did not ﬁnd
any differences in ﬁrmness between organic and
conventional kiwifruits after harvesting, but observed
a higher incidence of soft patches in conventional
kiwifruits after 10 days of storage." [Source](http://ucce.ucdavis.edu/files/datastore/234-708.pdf)

Comment: @chad the latter, yes

Comment: @Oddthinking I added a couple of sources.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about raw fruit?  Or any food?

Comment: @santiagozky - Then I suggest asking that question directly.  This question is not really answerable.  But "Are preservatives applied to commercially distrubted fruit?" is.

Comment: There is surely no doubt that wax is applied to some apples, is there?

Comment: I didn't want to specify the fruit in question to make it more useful for this site, but it seems that getting a general answer is rather impossible. The fruit in question was a plum. I dont think you can add wax to those.

Comment: Depends really. Sometimes there are preservatives, usually waxes to stop shrivelling, when on shelves. Most of the reason for firmness, etc, is down to conventional produce being picked before being ripe. Thus is lasts longer because it doesn't have the same ethylene content to deteriorate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Raffaele Porta et al. in 2013,  edible coatings was to found be extremely advantageous to preserve the characteristics of fresh-cut fruits and vegetables at their peak. A review of various preservative treatments for color preservation and preventing texture loss in fresh cut fruit and vegetables can be found [here](http://ucanr.org/sites/Zann_test/files/28711.pdf).

"Different technologies have been so far used to prolong the shelf-life of fresh-cut fruits and vegetables. Among these, almost all of the chemical treatments (sulfite, citric acid, ascorbic acid derivatives, cinnamate, benzoate, and cyclodextrins) confere off flavors, and many of the most effective substances added are recognized as [unsafe](http://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/edible-coating-as-packaging-strategy-to-extend-the-shelflife-of-freshcut-fruits-and-vegetables-2155-952X-3-e124.php?aid=22423#a1).

> A relatively simple technology, such as the application of edible coatings obtainable from inexpensive raw materials, is effective against both browning development and textural deterioration happening during the management and storage of fresh-cut products.